# Get all button's names in the scene and store them?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a lot of scenes in Unity and all of them have at least 12 buttons, each of the button has a name as a word from Dictionary (i.e : Ball, Human, Blue etc. etc.)

I would like to make a method that gets all the buttons in the current scene it is and stores them somewhere so later I can use that output**.name** to display them or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get the names of all objects that are buttons you could do something like what's documented here

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html

```
var names = FindObjectsOfType<Button>().Select(b => b.name);
```